# How to sort an NSMutableArray containing numbers as strings, in descending order

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sorting, numbers, nsmutablearray

I was sorting an **NSMutableArray** containing numbers as strings, in **descending order**. My array is in the same form as below:

```
{273,0,0,0,0,0,48,48,59,254}
```

I was looking for sorting it in descending order. That is expected result is:

```
{273,254,59,48,48,0,0,0,0,0}
```

I tried:

```
[[[myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] reverseObjectEnumerator] 
                                                                      allObjects];
```

The result was weird. It was:

```
{59,48,48,273,254,0,0,0,0,0} -- zeros are not getting sorted, and not proper sort
```

Then I tried:

```
[myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
```

Again wrong output (as below):

```
{0,0,0,0,0,254,273,48,48,59} -- zeros came first !!! and 273 in wrong position!!!
```

And I also tried:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                                       initWithKey:@"length" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Again... Result is as below:

```
{0,0,0,0,0,48,48,59,273,254} -- 273 in wrong position
```

I am totally confused. Do I need to check for those zeros? then whats happening with that 273? Am I wrong anywhere? Is there is any proper solution for me? Please help me finding out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This may help:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = ....... Your mutable array

NSArray *sorted_Array = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                            @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"intValue"
                                                            ascending:NO]]];
```

Keep Coding............ :)